# Take a row as a column without transpose

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe that I want to take only the values of one row, for all columns (as a numeric vector). One way of doing that would be `df_trasposed = t(df)`, and then I can just take the wanted column with `df_trasposed$column`

I feel there is a better way of doing it, without creating a new data frame and taking more memory. I tried something like `t(df)$column` but this won't work obviously.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
as.numeric(df['rowname',])
```

Comment: This creates `df['rowname',]` and then again `as.numeric(.)` as new objects in memory!

Answer (score 1):

Data frames are special types of lists, consisting of vectors of equal lengths. So we can treat it as lists and extract the *n*th element of each vector, where *n* is the row number of your data frame. *Example:*

```
df
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  5  9
# 2  2  6 10
# 3  3  7 11
# 4  4  8 12

sapply(df, `[`, 3)
# X1 X2 X3 
#  3  7 11
```

You can wrap an `unname(.)` around it to delete element names, but this probably creates another copy in memory and actually is just cosmetics.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 4, 3))
```